# Split series containing lists of strings into multiple columns

Tags: pandas

I'm using pandas to perform some string matching from a Twitter dataset.

I've imported a CSV of Tweets and indexed using the date. I've then created a new column containing text matches:

```
In [1]:
import pandas as pd
indata = pd.read_csv('tweets.csv')
indata.index = pd.to_datetime(indata["Date"])
indata["matches"] = indata.Tweet.str.findall("rudd|abbott")
only_results = pd.Series(indata["matches"])
only_results.head(10)

Out[1]:
Date
2013-08-06 16:03:17          []
2013-08-06 16:03:12          []
2013-08-06 16:03:10          []
2013-08-06 16:03:09          []
2013-08-06 16:03:08          []
2013-08-06 16:03:07          []
2013-08-06 16:03:07    [abbott]
2013-08-06 16:03:06          []
2013-08-06 16:03:02          []
2013-08-06 16:03:00      [rudd]
Name: matches, dtype: object
```

What I want to end up with is a dataframe, grouped by day/month, that I can plot the different search terms as columns and then plot.

I came across what looks like the perfect solution on another SO answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/16637607/2034487) but when trying to apply to this series, I'm getting an exception:

```
In [2]: only_results.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(1,index=x)).fillna(0)
Out [2]: Exception - Traceback (most recent call last)
...
Exception: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

I really want to be able to apply the changes within the dataframe to apply and reapply  groupby conditions and perform the plots efficiently - and would love to learn more about how the .apply() method works.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE AFTER SUCCESSFUL ANSWER**

The issue was with duplicates in the "matches" column that I hadn't seen. I iterated through that column to remove duplicates and then used the original solution from @Jeff linked above. This was successful, and I can now .groupby() on the resultant series to see daily, hourly, etc, trends. Here's an example of the resultant plot:

```
In [3]: successful_run = only_results.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(1,index=x)).fillna(0)
In [4]: successful_run.groupby([successful_run.index.day,successful_run.index.hour]).sum().plot()

Out [4]: <matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot at 0x110b51650>
```

[image: Plot grouped by day and hour]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got some duplicate result (e.g. Rudd appears more than once in a single tweet), hence the Exception (see below).

I think it's going to be preferable to count occurences rather than list from a findall (pandas datastructures aren't designed to contain lists, although str.findall uses them).
I would recommend using something like this:

```
In [1]: s = pd.Series(['aa', 'aba', 'b'])

In [2]: pd.DataFrame({key: s.str.count(key) for key in ['a', 'b']})
Out[2]: 
   a  b
0  2  0
1  2  1
2  0  1
```

Note (the exception because of the duplicate 'a's found in the first two rows):

```
In [3]: s.str.findall('a').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(1,index=x)).fillna(0)
#InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

Comment: Thanks @Andy - I'll run the code this morning (I'm in Sydney) and mark as accepted once I'm sorted.

Comment: I've marked this as accepted as it pointed out the main issue - the duplicates in the lambda function. I didn't actually need the duplicates, they were just 'tags' against the message. Instead of actually following @Andy's method, I de-duped the "matches" column and then successfully from Jeff in the earlier answer.

Answer (score 1):

First reset the index, then use the solution you mentioned:

```
In [28]: s
Out[28]:
Date
2013-08-06 16:03:17          []
2013-08-06 16:03:12          []
2013-08-06 16:03:10          []
2013-08-06 16:03:09          []
2013-08-06 16:03:08          []
2013-08-06 16:03:07          []
2013-08-06 16:03:07    [abbott]
2013-08-06 16:03:06          []
2013-08-06 16:03:02          []
2013-08-06 16:03:00      [rudd]
Name: matches, dtype: object

In [29]: df = s.reset_index()

In [30]: df.join(df.matches.apply(lambda x: Series(1, index=x)).fillna(0))
Out[30]:
                 Date   matches  abbott  rudd
0 2013-08-06 16:03:17        []       0     0
1 2013-08-06 16:03:12        []       0     0
2 2013-08-06 16:03:10        []       0     0
3 2013-08-06 16:03:09        []       0     0
4 2013-08-06 16:03:08        []       0     0
5 2013-08-06 16:03:07        []       0     0
6 2013-08-06 16:03:07  [abbott]       1     0
7 2013-08-06 16:03:06        []       0     0
8 2013-08-06 16:03:02        []       0     0
9 2013-08-06 16:03:00    [rudd]       0     1
```

Unless you have a clear use case for a `DatetimeIndex` (usually involves resampling of some kind, and no duplicates) you're better off putting your dates into a column, as it's more flexible than keeping it as an index, especially if said index has duplicates.

As far as the `apply` method goes, it does slightly different things for different objects. For example, `DataFrame.apply()` will apply the passed in callable across the columns by default, but you can pass `axis=1` to apply it along the rows.

`Series.apply()` applies the passed in callable to each element of the `Series` instance. In the case of the very clever solution provided by @Jeff, what's happening is the following:

```
In [12]: s
Out[12]:
Date
2013-08-06 16:03:17          []
2013-08-06 16:03:12          []
2013-08-06 16:03:10          []
2013-08-06 16:03:09          []
2013-08-06 16:03:08          []
2013-08-06 16:03:07          []
2013-08-06 16:03:07    [abbott]
2013-08-06 16:03:06          []
2013-08-06 16:03:02          []
2013-08-06 16:03:00      [rudd]
Name: matches, dtype: object

In [13]: pd.lib.map_infer(s.values, lambda x: Series(1, index=x)).tolist()
Out[13]:
[Series([], dtype: int64),
 Series([], dtype: int64),
 Series([], dtype: int64),
 Series([], dtype: int64),
 Series([], dtype: int64),
 Series([], dtype: int64),
 abbott    1
dtype: int64,
 Series([], dtype: int64),
 Series([], dtype: int64),
 rudd    1
dtype: int64]

In [14]: pd.core.frame._to_arrays(_13, columns=None)
Out[14]:
(array([[ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,   1.,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,   1.]]),
 Index([u'abbott', u'rudd'], dtype=object))
```

Each empty `Series` in `Out[13]` is given a value of `nan` to indicate that there is no value at the either of our column indices. In this case, that index is `Index([u'abbott', u'rudd'], dtype=object)`. Where there *is* a value at the column index it is retained.

Keep in mind that these are low-level details that users usually don't have to worry about. I was curious, so I followed the trail of code.

Comment: I don't *think* the reason for the exception is because of duplicates in the DatetimeIndex, but rather in the x of Series(1, index=x) (I could be wrong)....

Comment: @AndyHayden You're right. In fact, I can't reproduce the exception using the OP's data.

Comment: You can reproduce it with dupes in the findall (see my answer), I think Jeff's apply solution should work fine with dupes in the DatetimeIndex.

Comment: @AndyHayden It's when you have something like `['rudd', 'rudd']` in your data that this fails (as per your example). This is because you cannot create an indexer for a dupe `index`. Try `i = Index(['a', 'a']); i.get_indexer(i)`

Comment: oh, so this is more an exposition of Jeff's witty answer. (I was confused!)

Comment: Thanks @Phillip - your answer did help remove my confusion around the duplicate index, as I know that a pandas index will take duplicates in the index, so I now understand it's the index within the .apply() that was kicking out the error. Your explanation of how apply works as well is really useful, so even though it's not a solution to the original question it's really appreciated.