# Can you create smooth line plot within IPython using built-in methods?

Tags: python, matplotlib, d3.js, pandas

This is a next-step on from an earlier question: [Split series containing lists of strings into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614894/split-series-containing-lists-of-strings-into-multiple-columns)

For charts created using the pandas `.plot()` method, is there a straightforward way of smoothing the plot of each data series, without breaking out into matplotlib? Or is it even possible with matplotlib, or should I be looking at different backends? I'd love to be able to use the pandas series without breaking out into building up `.plot()`s from scratch.

For reference, here's the pseudocode of a figure I'm plotting (datetime index):

```
In [*]: dataframe.groupby([dataframe.index.day,dataframe.index.hour]).sum().plot()
```

[image]

Context:

*I understand there's a lot of discussion of using things like d3.js, and the developments towards using JS libraries and such in v2.0 over the coming months. If there's a current concensus on the 'best' way to create the kind of data visualisations that are commonly used on news websites and similar, I'd be happy to hear that and read up elsewhere.*

Comment: What have you tried in the way of smoothing?  Rolling average? Splines? Explicitly fitting to a known function?

Comment: Adding to what @tcaswell said, there are many different smoothing methods. `pandas` provides a few (`rolling_mean`, `ewma` to name a couple), there are many more in `scipy` (e.g., splines) and a few in `statsmodels` IIRC (LOWESS comes to mind). So, it really depends on what you're interested in doing with the smooth. Ultimately, you'll probably have to manipulate the plot produced by `Series.plot()`.

Comment: [Here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/computation.html#moving-rolling-statistics-moments) are the docs for the `rolling_*` functions in `pandas`.

Comment: As Phillip suggests, the simplest thing to do is probably to use a cubic spline as implemented in the scipy.interpolate.interp1d function. It should work well for the well-spaced data that you are showing here. There is a good example of the cubic spline here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html
If you don't like the way that looks, then you can play around with the other methods, like a rolling mean.