# Cumulative sum with missing categories in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following dataset

```
df_dict = ({'unit' : [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 'cat' : [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4], 
           'count' : [8, 3, 2, 2, 8, 7] })
df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)

df.set_index('unit', inplace = True)
```

Which looks like this:

```
    cat count
unit        
1    1   8
1    2   3
1    3   2
2    1   2
2    2   8
2    4   7
```

The count gives the frequency in which different categories where observed in a unit.
What I'd like to get is the cumulative frequency of the four categories for each unit. Note that category 4 is missing from unit 1 and category 3 is missing from unit 2.

Thus, the end result would be

for unit 1:

```
[8/13, 11/13, 13/13, 13/13]
```

and for unit 2:

```
[2/17, 10/17, 10/17, 17/17]
```

I know how to get the cumulative sum with `groupby` and `cumsum`, but then unit 1, for example, doesn't have a value for the missing category 4.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd


df_dict = ({'unit' : [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 'cat' : [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4], 
           'count' : [8, 3, 2, 2, 8, 7] })
df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)

df.set_index('unit', inplace = True)    

cumsum_count = df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['count'].cumsum().values, index=x['cat']))
# unit  cat
# 1     1       8
#       2      11
#       3      13
# 2     1       2
#       2      10
#       4      17
# dtype: int64

cumsum_count = cumsum_count.unstack(level=1).fillna(method='ffill', axis=1)
# cat   1   2   3   4
# unit               
# 1     8  11  13  13
# 2     2  10  10  17

totals = df.groupby(level=0)['count'].sum()
# unit
# 1       13
# 2       17
# Name: count, dtype: int64

cumsum_dist = cumsum_count.div(totals, axis=0)
print(cumsum_dist)
```

yields

```
cat          1         2         3  4
unit                                 
1     0.615385  0.846154  1.000000  1
2     0.117647  0.588235  0.588235  1
```

---

I really don't know how to explain this solution -- probably because I arrived at it somewhat serendipidously. Inspiration 
came from [Jeff's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16637607/190597), which used

```
s.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(1, index=x))
```

to associate values with an index. Once you've associated the  cumulative counts (*values*), e.g. [8,11,13], with the `cat` numbers (*index*), e.g. [1,2,3], you are basically home free. The rest is just standard applications of [unstack](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), [fillna](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), [div](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) and [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html#splitting-an-object-into-groups).

Comment: Thanks, really nice solution!! I still need to wrap my head around the values associated with the index thing...One quick question: Why do you need to use the `.values`  in  `cumsum().values` ? I don't get what that is doing.

Comment: Inside the `lambda` function, `x` is a DataFrame. `x['count'].cumsum()` is a Series. That Series has its own index which I'd like to replace by `x['cat']`. If we use `pd.Series(x['count'].cumsum(), index=x['cat'])`, then a `ValueError: cannot reindex ...` exception is raised because the original Series has duplicate entries in its index -- so it is unclear how to map from the old index to the new index. Every Series has a `values` attribute which returns the underlying data as a NumPy array. All we care about is the data, not the original index, so I used `.values` to pick off the data.