# Pandas creating new DataFrame from split columns with missing values, differing lengths

Tags: python, pandas

I have a bunch of categorical data that is concatenated together as a string (`string string string`, etc) in each of my rows. I need to separate these categorical data into columns so that I have something that looks like this:

```
       var1 var2 var3
row 1:    1    1    0
row 2:    0    0    1
row 3:    0    1    1   ....
```

The categorical data can be generated using this:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

np.random.seed(75)
a = [" ".join(np.unique(['var%d'%np.random.randint(5) for i in range(np.random.randint(10))])) for i in range(np.random.randint(10))]
a[0] = np.nan

b = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['descriptor'])
print(b)
```

And looks like this:

```
                 descriptor
0                       NaN
1                 var0 var1
2       var0 var1 var2 var3
3            var0 var2 var4
4                 var0 var4
5                      var3
6  var0 var1 var2 var3 var4
7            var0 var1 var2
```

And I would like to construct the following

```
   var0  var1  var2  var3  vars4
0     0     0     0     0      0
1     1     1     0     0      0
2     1     1     1     1      0
3     1     0     1     0      1
4     1     0     0     0      1
5     0     0     0     1      0
6     1     1     1     1      1
7     1     1     1     0      0
```

But I'm not sure how to approach this. The DataFrame is fairly large (25,000 rows with 5000 descriptors) so the method would have to be performant. I tried using `str.split(' ').tolist()`, but I'm not sure how to take that and convert it to the final product.

Answer (score 0):

First, fill the missing value with some kind of sentinel, and split the data.

```
b = b.fillna('_')
b['descriptor'] = b.str.split()
```

Then, using the approach from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16637171/pandas-reshaping-data/16637607#16637607), pivot into columns, and drop the sentinel.  This won't be ultra performant because of the apply, but probably reasonable on data of your size.

```
s = b['descriptor'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(1,index=x)).fillna(0).drop('_', axis=1)

In [115]: s
Out[115]: 
   var0  var1  var2  var3  var4
0     0     0     0     0     0
1     1     1     0     0     0
2     1     1     1     1     0
3     1     0     1     0     1
4     1     0     0     0     1
5     0     0     0     1     0
6     1     1     1     1     1
7     1     1     1     0     0
```