# Iterating through a list to create new columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a string column in dataframe like this:

```
ID  col1
id1 AA's 2015:45,BB:96
id2 Jigga:91,OO:73,BB:34
```

I want to create a new dataframe out of this which can take the shape:

```
ID  var1    var2    var3    var4
id1 45      96      0       0
id2 0       34      91      73
```

where `var1=AA's 2015,var2=BB,var3=Jigga,var4=OO`

I have stored all distinct values of string's first values in a list like this:

```
["AA's 2015","BB","Jigga","OO"]
```

I want to iterate through this list and for each value create a variable var[i]
which will take up it's value from col1 for that particular ID.

I can use the for loop for iterating through the list. But how to lookup the value and put in var[i]?

Any ideas will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to manipulate the strings into a pandas Series. The function passed to `apply` will be called on each string. The returned values, Series, are then merged into a single DataFrame. `apply`returns this DataFrame.

The DataFrame's column labels come from merging all the Series' indices. The merging also places the Series values in the appropriate columns, which thus yields the desired result:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['id1', 'id2'], 'col1': ["AA: 2015:45,BB:96", 'Jigga:91,OO:73,BB:34']})

result = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(
    dict([
        item for item in [
            part.rsplit(':',1) for part in x.split(',')] 
         if len(item)>1  # remove items corresponding to empty strings
    ]))).fillna(0)
result = result.rename(columns={name:'var{}'.format(i) for i, name in 
                                enumerate(result.columns, 1)})
result = pd.concat([df[['ID']], result], axis=1)
print(result)
```

yields

```
    ID var1 var2 var3 var4
0  id1   45   96    0    0
1  id2    0   34   91   73
```

I learned this trick [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16637607/190597).

Comment: thanks for the trick. I have situations where the col1 can have values like " AA: 2015:45" It splits AA and puts 2015:45 in values. Space with ":" is difference. Also, what to do when col1 is missing

Comment: Also, i wanted to create var[i], as string length can be long for a column name

Comment: If the final colon in each string separates the name from the value, then you could use `part.rsplit(':', 1)` to split the string at the rightmost colon. That might be cleaner than relying on a space preceding the colon. I've modified the code above to show what I mean. I've also renamed the columns `var1`, `var2`, etc....

Comment: What do you mean by "col1 is missing"? Do you mean that in some rows the value in the `col1` column is an empty string?

Comment: yes, the empty row is causing the error: "dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required"

Comment: I added a list comprehension with `if len(item)>1` at the end to filter out the lists containing empty strings.

Comment: Oops. Ran out of memory